Default program won't build on Anchor 0.30, ahash 0.84 no longer builds
I am attempting to build a default program on Anchor 0.30.
anchor init test-project
cd test-project
anchor build

Similar to this question, this error still occurs in Anchor 0.30:
error[E0658]: use of unstable library feature 'build_hasher_simple_hash_one'
   --> src/random_state.rs:463:5
    |
463 | /     fn hash_one<T: Hash>(&self, x: T) -> u64 {
464 | |         RandomState::hash_one(self, x)
465 | |     }
    | |_____^
    |
    = note: see issue #86161 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/86161> for more information
    = help: add `#![feature(build_hasher_simple_hash_one)]` to the crate attributes to enable

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0658`.

I have attempted to apply the fix from that issue - specifying an explicit version of ahash:
cargo add ahash@"=0.8.4"

However ahash 0.8.4 no longer builds on the new Anchor:
error[E0423]: expected function, found macro `transmute`
   --> /Users/mikemaccana/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/ahash-0.8.4/src/operations.rs:128:15
    |
128 |         xor ^ transmute::<_, u128>(vaesmcq_u8(vaeseq_u8(value, transmute!(0u128))))
    |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not a function
    |
help: consider importing one of these items instead
    |
1   + use core::mem::transmute;
    |
1   + use std::mem::transmute;
    |

error[E0423]: expected function, found macro `transmute`
   --> /Users/mikemaccana/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/ahash-0.8.4/src/operations.rs:161:15
    |
161 |         xor ^ transmute::<_, u128>(vaesimcq_u8(vaesdq_u8(value, transmute!(0u128))))
    |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not a function
    |
help: consider importing one of these items instead
    |
1   + use core::mem::transmute;
    |
1   + use std::mem::transmute;
    |

error[E0635]: unknown feature `stdsimd`
  --> /Users/mikemaccana/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/ahash-0.8.4/src/lib.rs:99:42
   |
99 | #![cfg_attr(feature = "stdsimd", feature(stdsimd))]
   |                                          ^^^^^^^


System details
% anchor -V
anchor-cli 0.30.0

% cargo build-sbf --version
solana-cargo-build-sbf 1.17.25
platform-tools v1.37
rustc 1.68.0

% solana -V
solana-cli 1.17.25 (src:d0ed878d; feat:3580551090, client:SolanaLabs)


After trying multiple ahash releases, it seems the only way to resolve the issue was to use the beta version of Solana CLI (ie 1.18), and also explicitly set the solana-program crate to a version that matches what is installed:
sh -c "$(curl -sSfL https://release.solana.com/beta/install)"

And then to build:
anchor init project
cd project 
cargo add solana-program@"=1.18.5"
anchor build

